# Trying to fill table with random dta but receive empty set

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-connector

I have a task to fill the table with 100 random records. I have created lists of random data and used in order to put it in a table. Program executes correctly with no problems. However, if I try to select data, I receive and empty set.`select * from products; Empty set (0.00 sec)`

```
import mysql.connector
import random

db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='127.0.0.1',
    user="root",
    passwd="11111111",
    database="test_database"
    )
db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()

db_cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE products(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(64), size 
VARCHAR(64))")

for i in range(100):
    color = random.choice(['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Black', 'White', 'Orange'])
    gender = random.choice(["Men's", "Women's"])
    clothing = random.choice(['Jeans', 'Shirt', 'T-Shirt', 'Cardigan', 'Skirt', 'Dress', 'Belt'])
    name = '%s %s %s' % (color, gender, clothing)
    sizes = random.choice([['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'], ['36', '38', '40', '42']])
    for size in sizes:
        db_cursor.execute('INSERT INTO products(name, size) VALUES(%s, %s)', (name, size))
```

Comment: `db_cursor.commit()`, add that after your insert queries, without committing your inserts are, for the lack of a better word, not commited

Comment: @python_user I receive `AttributeError: 'MySQLCursor' object has no attribute 'commit'`

Comment: my bad, it must be `db_connection.commit()` use the connection to commit, the cursor can not commit